# how to enable PHP_DIO?

Tags: php, serial-port

I did the following steps to use the PHP_DIO extension but it ain't working.

1. I downloaded the extension from https://pecl.php.net/package/dio
2. paste it in php/ext/
3. restarted xampp after editing php.ini file, added `extension=php_dio` in it

but still the fatal shows up, please help me to solve it, tnx

here's the `php` script:

```
$fd = dio_open('/dev/ttyS0', O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
dio_fcntl($fd, F_SETFL, O_SYNC);

dio_tcsetattr($fd, array(
    'baud' => 19200,
    'bits' => 8,
    'stop'  => 1,
    'parity' => 0
));

while (1) {

    $data = dio_read($fd, 1024);

    if ($data) {
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check extension_dir directive in your phpinfo() output?

Comment: @Rahul Yes I did, it was `C:\xampp\php\ext` which is the correct path

Comment: check if it's showing like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wZZk7.png)

Comment: @Rahul no it doesn't! why ?!?!

Comment: Follow this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.enable-dl)

Comment: @Rahul sry I can't quiet understand it, does it mean that I should add `dl('php_dio.dll')` in my code?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198572/discussion-between-arian-s-and-rahul).